# Why is the BeginConnect Method in VBA not recognizing a shape's name?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a connector shape to link to circle shapes in VBA. However, I get a mismatch error related to the shape name, when i try to specify the ConnectedShape for the BeginConnect.

The connector is created - thats not a problem, but it doesnt then reposition the beginning of the connector to the shape I have mentioned. The shape name is printing and its also the name of the shape within the sheet, so i dont understand why it's not working.

Does anyone know why?

This is the creation of the first shape.

```
Sub Node_Gen_S00()
    Call RESTART
    
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To rndNodeAmount_S00
        
        NodePosVer_RND = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 0)
        NodePosHor_RND = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 0)
        
        Set SectorSheet = Worksheets(1)
        Set SectorNodes = SectorSheet.Shapes
        
        Set Sector00_Node = SectorNodes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 126 + NodePosHor_RND, (Map_Median + 17.5), 10, 10)
        
        Sector00_Node.Name = "Sector00_Node0" & i
            With Sector00_Node.Fill
                .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 80, 80)
                .Transparency = 0.3

            End With
            With Sector00_Node.Line
                .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 80, 80)
                .Transparency = 0.6
            End With
        
        Debug.Print ("Node Name:" & Sector00_Node.Name)
        
    Next i
End Sub
```

This is the code for the creation of the second set of shapes.

```
Sub Node_Gen_S01()
    Call RESTART
    
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To rndNodeAmount_S01
        
        NodePosVer_RND = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(-15, 15)
        NodePosHor_RND = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(-40, 40)
        
        Set SectorSheet = Worksheets(1)
        Set SectorNodes = SectorSheet.Shapes
        
        Set Sector01_Node = SectorNodes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 385 + NodePosHor_RND, ((Map_Median + NodePosVer_RND) - (S01_Range_Ver / 2) + ((S01_Range_Ver / (rndNodeAmount_S01 + 1)) * i) + NodePosVer_RND), 15, 15)
        
        Debug.Print ("Node Name:" & Sector01_Node.Name)
        
        Sector01_Node.Name = ("Sector01_Node0" & i)
            With Sector01_Node.Fill
                .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(51, 204, 204)
                .Transparency = 1
                .TwoColorGradient msoGradientFromCenter, 1
                .GradientStops(2).Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                .GradientStops(2).Position = 0.5
            End With
            With Sector01_Node.Line
                .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 80, 80)
            End With
        
        Debug.Print ("Node Name:" & Sector01_Node.Name)
        
        
        
        ' GENERATE NODE CONNECTIONS -----------------------------------------------------------
        Set Sector01_Node_Connect = SectorNodes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 0, 0, 100, 100)

        With Sector01_Node_Connect.ConnectorFormat
            .BeginConnect ConnectedShape:=Sector00_Node01, ConnectionSite:=1
            .EndConnect ConnectedShape:=Sector01_Node01, ConnectionSite:=1
        End With
        
        With Sector01_Node_Connect.Line
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(51, 204, 204)
            .Weight = 1
        End With
        
        Sector01_Node_Connect.Name = "C_S0_S1_1"
                
        Sector01_Node_Connect.RerouteConnections
        
        
    Next i

End Sub
```

I'm getting the error on this line:
.BeginConnect ConnectedShape:=Sector00_Node01, ConnectionSite:=1

The strange thing is that in another set of code, it works and there is no issue with the shape name:

```
Function GenerateNodes()

Set SectorSheet = Worksheets(1)
Set SectorNodes = SectorSheet.Shapes

'GENERATING TEST NODES ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Set Sector01_Node01 = SectorNodes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 800, 240, 15, 15)

Sector01_Node01.Name = "potato"
    With Sector01_Node01.Fill
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 1
        .TwoColorGradient msoGradientFromCenter, 1
        .GradientStops(2).Color = RGB(51, 204, 204)
        .GradientStops(2).Position = 0.9
    End With
    With Sector01_Node01.Line
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(51, 204, 204)
    End With


Set Sector01_Node02 = SectorNodes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 1100, 240, 15, 15)

Sector01_Node02.Name = "Sector01_Node02"
    With Sector01_Node02.Fill
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(51, 204, 204)
        .Transparency = 1
        .TwoColorGradient msoGradientFromCenter, 1
        .GradientStops(2).Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .GradientStops(2).Position = 0.5
    End With
    With Sector01_Node02.Line
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(51, 204, 204)
    End With




' GENERATING TEST LINE BETWEEN NODES ----------------------------------------------------------

Set Sector01_Node01_Connect = SectorNodes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 0, 0, 100, 100)

With Sector01_Node01_Connect.ConnectorFormat
    .BeginConnect ConnectedShape:=Sector01_Node01, ConnectionSite:=1
    .EndConnect ConnectedShape:=Sector01_Node02, ConnectionSite:=1
End With

With Sector01_Node01_Connect.Line
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(51, 204, 204)
    .Weight = 1
End With

Sector01_Node01_Connect.Name = "S01_C_01_02"


Sector01_Node01_Connect.RerouteConnections

End Function
```

Comment: You should be passing a Shape **object**, not the *name* of a shape.

Comment: Thanks Rory, that makes sense. So what would be the designation of the object  in my case? I thought the name would be used to indicate which object the connector should attach to.

Comment: It looks like it should be: `SectorNodes("Sector00_Node01")`